# How do I pull the table data from this website?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, web-scraping

Using the below code, I can't pull the College Football matchups from pregame.com in the game center.

I've tried multiple class ids with different elements, and even tried pulling with pandas, but can't get the entire table. Is there another way to scrape it successfully?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import lxml
import requests


header = {'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/95.0.4638.54 Safari/537.36'}
pregame = requests.get('https://pregame.com/game-center/?d=1636174800000&t=0&l=2&a=0&s=AwayRot&m=false&b=undefined&o=Current&c=All&k=', 'r').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(pregame, 'lxml')

div = soup.find_all('p', class_ = 'pggc-col-data pggc-away')
print(div)
```

Comment: what data are you after here? You don't need Selenium.

Comment: I'm looking to get all the Opening lines, Cash %, Money%, etc. from the College Football Game Center. Basically, that entire table excluding anything to the right of "Picks"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to do a little data manipulation and joins depending what you are after. But you can get the data back in json format from the api and parse it.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://socket.pregame.com/api/gamecenter/bootstrap'

jsonData = requests.get(url).json()

data = {}
for each, v in jsonData.items():
    data[each] = pd.DataFrame(v)

for key, table in data.items():
    print(f'\n*** {key} ***')
    print(table.head(10).to_string())


leagues_dict = dict(zip(data['Leagues']['Name'],data['Leagues']['Id']))

final_data = {}
for k, v in leagues_dict.items():
    
    events_df = data['Events'][data['Events']['LeagueId'] == v].rename(columns={'Id':'EventId'})
    groups_df = data['Groups'][data['Groups']['LeagueId'] == v].rename(columns={'Id':'EventGroupId'})
    odds_df = data['Odds'][data['Odds']['LeagueId'] == v]
    scores_df = data['Scores']
    
    final_df = events_df.merge(groups_df.drop('LeagueId', axis=1), how='left', on='EventGroupId')
    final_df = final_df.merge(odds_df.drop('LeagueId', axis=1), how='right', on='EventId')
    
    if len(scores_df) > 0:
        final_df = final_df.merge(scores_df, how='left', on='EventId')
    
    final_data.update({k:final_df})
```

You can always just write this to csv and view in excel then too if it's easier for you to work with.

Comment: Did you strip the whitespace somewhere? Mine doesn't look as clean as yours.

Comment: No I don’t. Not sure why yours would look any different

Comment: Hmmm very strange. Mine is all over the place. Looks like everything separated by tabs. Regardless, thank you for the help. I’ll mess around with the code you provided and try to pull only the CFB matchups

Comment: Might just be the console size. You may just need to format.

Comment: I really appreciate your help. On the last two rows, I'm getting a KeyError for 'EventID'. I've tried changing the name to other Columns, but I still seem to always get the keyError.

Comment: One other question if you don't mind...anytime you do a 'for' loop, and its something like 'for x, y in (blank):...the x is always the index, right? and the second is the variable?

Comment: Not always. if you do .iterrows(), then yes. if you do .items(), its doing key, values of a dictionary

Comment: also fixed the issue. The scores dataframe was empty (since there no scores currently). So they must have resfreshed the data at some point between when I posted the code and when you ran it

Answer (score 1):

the problem you're running into is that the data is being loaded dynamically via javascript.

You'll want to check out something like Selenium to work around this. Here's a good overview: [How to Scrape Data From JavaScript-Based Website Using Python, Selenium, and Headless Web Driver](https://thinkdiff.net/how-to-scrap-data-from-javascript-based-website-using-python-selenium-and-headless-web-driver-531c7fe0c01f)